# Extracting numbers from string into an array

Tags: c++

I'm having a problem with an assignment. I have to open a text file that looks more or less like this:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
|ammount        |       time            |delay              |
-------------------------------------------------------------
|100            |       342             | 4324              |
```

with a few more rows. All I have to do is get the numbers into an array, which, for the example above, would look like this: `ar[0]=100, ar[1]=342, ar[2]=4324`. I imagine that I need to read the file line by line into strings with getline, but what next? If I use `stringstream`, I would get `|100` instead of just `100`. I'm really out of ideas now.

Answer (score 0):

To read one line of input like you described (`file` may be an `ifstream` or a `istringstream` here):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
{
    file.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '|'); // Ignores all characters until it finds a '|' character
    file >> ar[i];  // Reads the number following the '|' to ar[i]
}
file.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n'); // Finally, ignores all characters until newline
```

You can even make a small shortcut macro if you want:

```
#define ignore_until(c) ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), c)
```

and use it like this:

```
file.ignore_until('|');
```